# What is the industry standard approach to disable weak ciphers to mitigate vulnerabilities?

Tags: tls, iis

Particularly this question is focused for Windows Server 2008 R2.

I know the registry can be used to modify particular entries to disable weak ciphers if they are known.

I saw this tool: http://www.defensia.co.il/2011/05/12/hardening-iis-ssl-with-iiscrypto-disabling-weak-ciphers/ but I'm not familiar with the creator so I'm not too trusting of it.

I'm sure there may be a template to use of some sort, but I'm not familiar with the exact details of that.

Comment: Are you only talking about SSL/TLS on IIS, or about other kinds of encryption too?

Comment: Mainly vulnerabilities for IIS so SSL/TLS would be most definitely desired to modify.  Otherwise, I'm not sure if other ciphers for encryption would be necessary unless they pose a threat and serve no major purpose other than expose vulnerabilities.

Comment: Are you looking for a tool/script to disable them? Generally for platforms we would just update the Group Policy and push it out to servers/desktops, and for IIS/Apache we would update the config to disable weak ciphers.

Comment: If a tool is known that would be extra knowledge, but ideally the Group Policy rules you mention would be better.  Do you have reference to a book or link that identifies where those settings are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SSL/TLS, you can control this setting through group policy on 2008 or later systems (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb870930%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
The setting is called SSL Cipher Suite Order and is inside of the Administrative Templates/Network hierarchy.

If you need to modify the behavior of other applications that utilize the SChannel crypto framework on the system, you can modify the registry values directly http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245030.